# The "shuffle" choice has disappeared from my iPod classic 160GB

Tags: ipod-classic

The shuffle choice has disappeared from my iPod classic 160GB. Can this be found again?
I am very clueless with IT so would appreciate basic instructions if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for the word "shuffle" or the symbol for shuffle?

Comment: I have now resolved this problem but thank you for offering to help.